# Remove the scroll in the Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

Visual Studio: 2010 Proffesional

Can you please tell how in the window with a list of files in a project to remove the vertical scroll bar?

[image]

Comment: Why is that an issue? Are you getting that scroll-bar when no files are in that view?

Comment: I would like to remove) to the work area can be removed using scrolls:

  Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> Display and deselect the "Vertical scroll bar" and / or "Horizontal scroll bar"

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  You need that to be able to see all of your files.